# 64 bit integer comparison in HAProxy acl rule

Tags: apache, load-balancing, haproxy

I have following acl rules to check the range of my url_param value.

```
acl small       urlp_val(uid) le 311111111111000000
acl medium       urlp_val(uid) 311111111111000001:311111111111001000
acl large       urlp_val(uid) ge 311111111111001001
```

The number are 64 bit integers. This comparison doesn't seem to be working. It always redirect to only one instance. If I decrease the numbers to a range of say 1 to 100, it works well. Does it not support 64 bit numbers or am I doing something stupid/silly here?

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.7/configuration.html#7.1.2) always uses "int" and "integer" to talk about this type. If you check the source code, you'll see that [`smp_fetch_url_param_val`](https://github.com/haproxy/haproxy/blob/v1.6.0/src/proto_http.c#L11833) uses [`strl2ic`](https://github.com/haproxy/haproxy/blob/v1.6.0/src/standard.c#L1591) which returns an `int`, not a `long`.

So no, you can't extract 64bit values with `urlp_val`.

Answer (score 0):

I am had a similar task. I solved it by cutting off the last 6 characters from a large number and comparing only the first part.

```
# my case: if some_id >= 9089000000 use backend_2

acl is_number_long urlp_reg('some_id') '^\d{7,}$'
acl is_first_part_great urlp('some_id'),regsub('\d{6}$','') -m int gt 9088

use_backend backend_2 if is_number_long is_first_part_great

default_backend backend_1
```

You can try something like this:

```
# some_id = 311111111111000000 -> first_part = 311111111, last_part = 111000000

acl is_number_long urlp_reg('some_id') '^\d{10,}$'

acl is_first_part_gt urlp('some_id'),regsub('\d{9}$','') -m int gt 311111111
acl is_first_part_eq urlp('some_id'),regsub('\d{9}$','') -m int eq 311111111

acl is_last_part_gt urlp('some_id'),regsub('^.*(\d{9})$','\1') -m int gt 111000000
acl is_last_part_lt urlp('some_id'),regsub('^.*(\d{9})$','\1') -m int lt 111001001

use_backend backend_3 if is_number_long is_first_part_gt                                  # large
use_backend backend_3 if is_number_long is_first_part_eq !is_last_part_lt                 # large

use_backend backend_2 if is_number_long is_first_part_eq is_last_part_gt is_last_part_lt  # medium

default_backend backend_1                                                                 # small
```